# Spring application with embedded jetty can't find webdefault.xml if running from jar

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jetty

I have spring application which uses embedded Jetty instance.

```
project
   | src
      | controller
      | webapps
          | jsp
          | WEB-INF
              | web.xml
              | applicationContext.xml
              | spring-servlet.xml
```

my jar has the same tree structure but I keep getting

```
    d:\test>java -jar springtest.jar
2011-11-22 15:37:02.576:INFO::jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2011-11-22 15:37:02.686:WARN::Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,[file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-webapps-_-any-/webinf
/, jar:file:/d:/test/springtest.jar!/org/jcvi/webapps/]}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\test\org\eclipse\jetty\webapp\webdefault.xml (The system cannot find
the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
        at org.jcvi.ServerRunner.startServer(ServerRunner.java:83)
        at org.jcvi.MainServer.main(MainServer.java:18)
2011-11-22 15:37:02.748:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
```

I have following java class which runs jetty server instance

```
String webDir = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("webapps").toExternalForm();
Server server = new Server(8080);

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setResourceBase(webDir);
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, new DefaultHandler() });
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
```

my web.xml looks like

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

this application runs fine if I run inside IDE, but it fails with JAR.
How can I resolve this issue so that I can have single jar file which has the web application in it?

Comment: Did you set "d:\test\org\eclipse\jetty\webapp\webdefault.xml" or parts of it somewhere?

Comment: yes i did. it is from jetty-webapp jar and is under {myjar}\org\eclipse\jetty\webapp. Do i still need to set default descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solve it with this main class implementation:

```
private static final int PORT = 8080;
private static final String WAR_LOCATION = "src/webapps"; //in your case I guess
private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/movence"; //change it if you want

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

    setupConnector(connector);
    setupContext(server, context);
    setupServer(server, context, connector);
    startServer(server);
}

private static void startServer(Server server) throws Exception, InterruptedException {
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

private static void setupServer(Server server, WebAppContext context, SocketConnector connector) {
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
    server.addHandler(context);
}

private static void setupConnector(SocketConnector connector) {
    connector.setPort(PORT);
}

private static void setupContext(Server server, WebAppContext context) {
    context.setServer(server);
    context.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    context.setWar(WAR_LOCATION);
}
```

Comment: d:\test>java -jar test.jar
2011-11-23 14:10:21.407:INFO::jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2011-11-23 14:10:22.438:WARN::Web application not found /webapp
2011-11-23 14:10:22.441:WARN::Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},/webapp
this is what I got..

Comment: It's strange cause Jetty is trying to access the folder /webapp while your descriptor is in /webapps. Have you tried to rename the /webapps folder just to see what would happen?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that jetty's trying to parse the web.xml (descriptor) file, but thinks its in

```
.../...../...../webdefault.xml
```

or something like that.

You should explicitly set the web.xml path:

```
context.setDescriptor("WEB-INF/web.xml"); `
```

or, assuming that your jar really does include the aformentioned 'project' dir (which isn't standard jar intrernal layout):

```
context.setDescriptor("project/src/webapps/WEB-INF/web.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

From @Trein's post, setting the WAR_LOCATION is important. I have seen jetty failing to deploy the web app when this is missing.

Assuming that you are using Jetty to test your app, if you are using Maven POM below is how I test my web app

### pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet-tester</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.22</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat</id>
 <build>
        <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.22</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                            <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                            <webAppSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <systemProperty>
                                    <name>RESOURCE_PATH</name>
                                    <value>${project.build.outputDirectory}</value>
                                </systemProperty>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <connectors>
                                <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                                    <port>9090</port>
                                    <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                                </connector>
                            </connectors>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                    <daemon>true</daemon>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

To run the webapp you can either run `mvn jetty:start` or run mvn package. This starts the Jetty server on port 9090 and runs the tests (run your http based tests here) and shutdown the server/webapp.
If you want to run as standalone webapp, use `mvn jetty:start` and use your webapp just like any webapp container.

This all assumes you are using Maven. The code above provided by @Trein does the same programatically and the one I provided is the maven configuration equivalent of the above.

**Note**: You shouldn't worry about webdefault.xml as the default is already packaged in the jetty jar file. You should use your own webdefault.xml only when you need to extend/alter the defaults. There is either something wrong with your Jetty jar (if its reporting this or something to do with your CLASSPATH settings)

Comment: Please note that the `maven-jetty-plugin` is the old, obsolete name of the plugin that has not been updated for more than a year. The new plugin is called `jetty-maven-plugin` and resides at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Found this github project : 
https://github.com/steveliles/jetty-embedded-spring-mvc

This gives a basic startup template project based on maven. It embedded jetty with spring mvc.
Good place to start from scratch or to compare and debug what's wrong with current implementation.

The author has done a nice documentation here :
http://steveliles.github.io/setting_up_embedded_jetty_8_and_spring_mvc_with_maven.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little bit out-dated. However I recently encountered this problem in the context of embedding Jetty in an Eclipse OSGi application using the version of Jetty packaged with Eclipse (Jetty 8.x).

The way I sorted this out is the following :

1. Get the URL of the webdefault.xml relative to the org.eclipse.jetty.webapp bundle
2. Pass this URL to the context default descriptor

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(WebAppContext.class);
Enumeration<URL> urls = bundle.findEntries("/", "webdefault.xml", true);
String webdefaultURL = urls.nextElement().toExternalForm(); // Should check returned value 
mycontext.setDefaultsDescriptor(webdefaultURL);
```

Hope it helps

seb

Answer (score 0):

Your `webdefault.xml` (Jetty) is missing:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\test\org\eclipse\jetty\webapp\webdefault.xml

see ["What is webdefault.xml?"](http://irc.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/webdefault.xml)

If you have a custom location, you need to add it:

```
context.setDefaultsDescriptor("/my/path/to/webdefault.xml");
```