# Does Jetty still have WebAppContext?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm trying to run my spring MVC using an embedded instance.  I found this question: [Jetty Embedded Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233886/jetty-embedded-spring-application)

I am using jetty version: 7.6.2.v20120308, javax servlet: 2.5

I am using IntelliJ and the class WebAppContext doesn't seem to resolve to any package/namespace.  Does this class exist or has it been replaced?

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext ????????
}
```

Comment: Are you using Maven, or did you download the Jetty's ZIP and added the jars manually in the Eclipse classpath ?

Comment: I am using Maven to pull dependancies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to make sure, does your pom.xml contain this dependency ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.2.v20120308</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the dependency on *jetty-webapp*, connecting it to the server has changed:

from: `server.addHandler(webAppContext);`

to: `server.setHandler(webAppContext);`